# call from a class to another class in python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I'm new to python and I am trying to do something like this: I have two classes, one for building a GUI form, and another class to handle the request. the submit button is on the GUI form, and the handle action is in the handle class.

So I tried to call the handle class from the GUI class, so I did something like this:

```
class Appview:

    def __init__(self, master):

        master.title("Simple EXCEL")
        master.resizable(False, False)

        self.filename = ""
        self.input_file = ttk.Entry(self.frame_content, textvariable = self.filename, width = 24)
        self.input_file.grid(row = 2, column = 1, pady = 5, padx = 5)       
        ttk.Button(self.frame_content, text = "choose file", command = self.browse_file).grid(row = 2, column = 2)

        #ADDING#
        a = HandleData(self)
        ttk.Button(self.frame_content, text = "add", command = HandleData.submit).grid(row = 3, column = 0 ,columnspan = 3, pady = 5)

    """
    Choosing a file to browse
    """   
    def browse_file(self):
        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title = 'Choose a ffffile')
        self.input_file.insert(0, self.filename) #updating the file entry
```

and this is the Handle class:

```
class HandleData:

    def __init__(self):
        self.the_file = Appview.filename.get()

    def submit(self):
        messagebox.showinfo(title = "Okie Dokie", message = "well done: {}".format(self.the_file))
```

but I keep getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): 
>    File "C:\Users\Amir\workspace\Python Workout\main.py", line 91, in  if __ name__ == "__ main__": main() 
>    File "C:\Users\Amir\workspace\Python Workout\main.py", line 88, in main
>       appview = Appview(root) 
>    File "C:\Users\Amir\workspace\Python Workout\main.py", line 60, in __ init__
>       a = HandleData(self) 
>   TypeError: __ init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

any ideas please?

Comment: `a = Handle(self)` change to `a = Handle()`

Comment: then i get this new error:
`AttributeError: type object 'Appview' has no attribute 'filename'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do -

```
a = HandleData(self)
```

You are trying to create the instance (object) of `HandleData` , when creating an instance, the `__init__()` is called  (after the object has been created) with the first argument as the created instance itself, so when you send in `self` , it becomes the second argument for `__init__()` , but your `__init__()` in `HandleData` only accepts one argument , so the issue occurs.

You can make `HandleData` accept a second parameter which could be the AppView and then in the `HandleData.submit` , you can get the filename from this object. Example -

HandleData -

```
class HandleData:

    def __init__(self, appview):
        self.appview = appview

    def submit(self):
        filename = self.appview.filename
        messagebox.showinfo(title = "Okie Dokie", message = "well done: {}".format(filename))
```

This gets the data for `filename` from the instance variable `filename` in `AppView` , if you want the data from the Entry `input_file` , you can use -

```
filename = appview.input_file.get()
```

---

Why the changes to `submit()` and `HandleData` are required  is because we cannot get the filename when we do `__init__()` itself, because you create the object for `HandleData` in `AppView.__init__()` , so you have not selected any filename till then. So instead you are saving the `appview` object in `self.appview`and when `submit` button is clicked, you are accessing the `filename` attribute set to it and doing your logic.

Change in AppView class -

```
self.datahandler = HandleData(self)
ttk.Button(self.frame_content, text = "add", command = self.datahandler.submit).grid(row = 3, column = 0 ,columnspan = 3, pady = 5)
```

Comment: ok thank u, so I did something like this:<br />
`
    def __init__(self, Appview):
        self.appview = Appview
                
    def submit(self):
        self.the_file = appview.filename
        messagebox.showinfo(title = "Okie Dokie", message = "well done: {}".format(self.the_file))
`

and I get this error: `self.the_file = appview.filename
NameError: name 'appview' is not defined`

 PS: how I add a comment in here, in a way I can edit it normally?

Comment: Made some small changes check now.

Comment: thanks again for the reply. now again nothing happens, it looks like it doesn't get anything from `self.appview.filename` in the the HandleData class. I am using python 3.4 if it makes any differnce...

Comment: try printing `filename` what comes? have you selected a file before clicking?

Comment: I tried this and I also tried to print from DataHandke a variable that I defined in AppView but it doesn't printing anything. like the appview object inside the HandleData class is empty or something

Comment: hmm if appview were empty you would get some other error. Are you sure you had selected browse and selected a file before clicking on submit?

Comment: embarrassing... I didn't choose a file, I just wrote some 'bla bla' text in the input field... why is it differnet?

Comment: because `filename` is only set when you select a file, if you want to get the data in the entry use - `filename = appview.input_file.get()` in the submit function.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = HandleData(self)
```

Look at this, what are you passing though self? A reference of the class, you are in. But `HandleData` needs the reference of the class which it belong, and it automatically get it.

So, it basically gets 2 parameter, where 1 should be got.

Try:

```
a = HandleData()
```

Comment: thanks, but then i get this new error: `AttributeError: type object 'Appview' has no attribute 'filename'`

Comment: Ok, then add a parameter `appview` in handleData's __init__ , and then you have access to the attribute. Then initialize handleData like: `a= HandleData(appview) `, You can call with `self` too, becaue that will pass the current class reference.

Answer (score 0):

You need and extra parameter in your `__init__` function to hold the second class:

```
def __init__(self, other_class):
    self.the_file = other_class.filename.get()
```

And then you can call it like you do:

```
a = HandleData(self)
```

Because in this case `self` refers to the `AppView` class. When in the `HandleData` class' `__init__` function it refers to the `HandleData` class.

Look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) here about classes.

Comment: thanks you, now my class looks like this:
`class HandleData:
   def __init__(self, Appview):
      #self.appview = Appview
      self.the_file = Appview.filename
        
   def submit(self):
      messagebox.showinfo(title = "Okie Dokie", message = "well done: {}".format(self.the_file))
`

I ge no errors, yet nothing happens. it looks like it didn't pass the variable `filename`

PS: how I add a comment in here, in a way I can edit it normally?